# Is there a Bitcoin ATM in London?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, bitcoin-atm

Now I know there is one Bitcoin ATM in Vancouver, Canada. Is there a Bitcoin ATM in London? If yes, where is it located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be Robocoin ATM's in London and Bristol this Spring. https://twitter.com/satoshipoint

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not Bitcoin ATM in London. There are only two ATM machines at the moment. One in Canada and the other one about to go live in Hong Kong. Brazil is getting one soon.

But there are currently "human ATM's" in London via [local bitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/). They will buy and sell Bitcoins. Just meet up with one of them at your favourite pub.

In case you see business opportunities and want to start your own check https://robocoinkiosk.com and https://lamassu.is/ or DYI and build it!

Answer (score 0):

There are currently 2 Bitcoin ATMs in London, you can find them listed here http://coinsonar.co.uk/